# iPhone cocoa : UITableViewCell background not displaying the color set into IB

Tags: iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, background-color

I made a custom cell for a UITableView (subclassing UITableViewCel, e..., and with a xib). In IB, i set the background color of the myUITableViewCell to a light grey. Simulated into IB (with a run), the cell looks great (a full grey even under the disclosure button). But when I run the application, the cell keeps showing a white background. Do you know why this happens ?

May I have to do this programmaticaly to make it work ?

Comment: have you tried setting this in code: `tableCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a great help at : [Setting background color of a table view cell on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900094/setting-background-color-of-a-table-view-cell-on-iphone)

In fact it seems that this behaviour needs coding... a very few lines, as the color set in IB is cleared at draw time. So the background color have to be set in the "willDisplayCell" tableview delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

Do you init the cell with initWithNibName:@"YOURXIBFILE" ...?
Did you overwrite the drawRect Method?

Comment: Yes, of course, I init the cell with initWithNibName:@"YOURXIBFILE" and try to reuse it before (pattern matching the default apple sample code for a TableView project). But I didn't override drawrect method. Everything is done into IB, so I don't see why I should override it.

Answer (score 0):

yea, there is some problems to create custem cell with IB.

try write it in code, you can see a tutorial how to do this:

http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=284