# iPhone Dev, UITableView Background Color

Tags: iphone, uitableview, colors, background

I am having a problem with the background color of my table view.  In Interface Builder, I have the background color set, and it shows correctly there.  When I run my application, however, there is no background color there (it is the default white).

I have discovered that I can set the background color in the table view delegate file:

```
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightTextColor];
```

The problem with that is I want to use one of the colors out of the Crayon palette.

So, is there some reason that the background color isn't showing up in the first place?  Or, if I have to override it like my code example above, how can I set it to one of the Crayon colors?

Any help is much appreciated!

---

I JUST realized that IB will tell you the RGB values of any colors, you just have to switch the slider from Grey Sliders to RGB Slider when setting the colors.  I didn't even realize that was an option.  So, the lesson of a newbie has been learned!

---

Alright, in my case I wanted to color my table "Mercury."  To do this, I used IB to tell me what the RGB value of that color was (change the slider from Gray to RGB).  The RGB values for Mercury were 230, 230, 230.  I then modified Jason's code and placed it the numberOfRowsInSection method of my tableView delegate.

```
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:230.0f/255.0f green:230.0f/255.0f blue:230.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

Things to note: Don't forget to include your f's!  Otherwise you'll wind up with all zeros -- aka, black.

This worked like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[try here](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/liven-up-your-boring-uitableview-part-1/)

[or here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281515/how-to-customize-the-background-color-of-a-uitableviewcell)

[or even here....](http://www.google.com/search?q=uitableview+background+color+cell+colour)

The reason might simply be that your cells are coloured white, not transparent so you cant see the colour below.

Comment: I colored the cells transparent, and that didn't change anything.  Thanks for the links though, those look very promising!  I will look into it further tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: which view did you set as transparent? The contentView or the backgroundView?

Comment: As far as I recall, the backgroundView. I would have to look it up though.  Still haven't gotten a chance to look into the links yet, I shall do that today.

Comment: I wound up using the other solution, but I just wanted you to know that I really appreciated the help, and the links.  Thanks!