# change table view's cell selection color

Tags: iphone

can we change the selection color of table view, i.e cell, by default its blue, so, can we change it to any other color?

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this way in code

```
aCell.selectedBackgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] 
      initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedBackground.png"]] autorelease];
```

or you can set it in interface builder to gray, I think blue and grey is all that is available without creating a be view

Comment: thanks aaron, i already used this snippet, i dont want to give image,cant we just color only. thanks for relpy... appreciated

Comment: further googling led me to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281515/how-to-customize-the-background-color-of-a-uitableviewcell

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this, that doesn't require an image file is:

```
UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] init];
// At least on iOS6 you don't to size the view for this to work.
bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
aCell.selectedBackgroundView = bgView;
```