# Change background cell on tableView?

Tags: ios4

I want change background of all cells in a tableView, I have used initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 how type of cell, (because I want this type but background is white) I do not want to change the background of Tableview but only the cell, is this possible?

Comment: Here's [a simpler answer and much more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281515/how-to-customize-the-background-color-of-a-uitableviewcell/2803123#2803123). (1-st result from [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=uitableviewcell+background), btw ;) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That style of table cell consists of two labels, one with the main text on the left, and a second with blue text on the right.

Try setting the background colors of the label cells:

```
tableCell.textLabel.backgroundColor = ...
tableCell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = ...
```

Edit: You also need to set the background color of the tableCell's contentView.

```
tableCell.contentView.backgroundColor = ...
```

Edit 2: The following code also ensures that the background color extends to the accessory

```
UIColor *bgColor = [UIColor greenColor];
tableCell.textLabel.text = @"abc";
tableCell.textLabel.backgroundColor = bgColor;

tableCell.detailTextLabel.text = @"def";
tableCell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = bgColor;

tableCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

tableCell.backgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
tableCell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = bgColor;
```

Comment: i have use: cell.contentView.backgroundcolor... but for change color to cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator; how can make?

Comment: AFAIR, you can throw away everything above the last two lines from the last code snippet

Comment: I've tried this and if you don't set the background colors of the textLabel and detailLabel then they will just be white.