# Specify backgroundcolor in grouped UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, background-color

Is there a way to set the **selected** background color for a cell ? For the moment I'm using this code :

```
    UIImageView* selectedBackgroundCell = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectNull] autorelease];
    [selectedBackgroundCell setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_hover_bg.png"]];
    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:selectedBackgroundCell];


    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_bg.png"]]];
```

and here is the result : 
[image]

Unfortunately, the border doesn't draw well during the selected mode, as I expected.
Do you know how to fix this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to customize the background/border colors of a grouped table view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400965/how-to-customize-the-background-border-colors-of-a-grouped-table-view)

Comment: also duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281515/how-to-customize-the-background-color-of-a-uitableviewcell

Comment: not a duplicate. I manage to add a background color, but not a selected background color. Thks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the only way is to create 2 new images: header and footer, and load them when the requested row is the first or last.

Comment: is there a delegate methods which specifies whether or not a cell is selected ? like cellWillBeSelected and cellWillBeUnselected ?

Comment: tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath: 
Check the reference here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: unfortunately this methods deosn't implement this comportement. I've already tried it. Thanks for helping.