# How to create login and password fields same as in facebook app for iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to create login and password fields same as in facebook app for iOS. Here is screenshot:
[image]

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best way I think you need to create a Custom TableView Cell and Add a textField under it with textField borderStyle being `UITextBorderStyleNone`. Also you can give a placeholder string as "Email" and "Password" in respective textFields.

**EDIT:**

You can have two sections in tableView. `Section 0` will contain textFields and `Section 1` will have Login Button.

For the Login button, you just need to give the [background color to contentView of the cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281515/how-to-customize-the-background-color-of-a-uitableviewcell) to make it work as a button. And `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` for Section 1 & Row 0 (i.e Login button) will work like button's TouchUp Inside Event.

**EDIT-1:**

Thanks to @MichaelFrederick suggestion, I got a better solution where in we can create a view with Login button in it and return the view from below method:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return yourLoginButtonView;
}
```

Let me know if you need more help.

Hope this helps

Comment: @TimurMustafaev: Let me know if you require any further help. I am always happy to help. :)

Comment: the button doesn't have to be it's own section, you can just wrap the button in a UIView and set that UIView as the tableFooterView.

Comment: @MichaelFrederick: Yes thanks. I agree.. I am still learning. Thanks.. Yours is a better idea.. :)

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a customised `UITableView` used as a subview. But there are lots of ways of going about this, from using plain old custom `UIView`s to having the shape as a background, with text input overlaid on top.