# Setting background color of cell not working - IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to customize the background color of a UITableViewCell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281515/how-to-customize-the-background-color-of-a-uitableviewcell)

I am trying to set the text color of a cell but it is not working. Here is the code..

```
cell_center.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
cell_center.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
cell_center.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
```

Here selection style is working but text color not affecting. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @HelmiB Not like that, I have asked few questions only, one or two questions I got proper answer, remaining it didn't worked for me. Now here its worked thanks for that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cell_center.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: you should accept an answer you find it helps you.

Answer (score 9):

Set the background color of `contentView` like this:

```
[cell_center contentView].backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually wanted to set your TEXT color but you did not even do that. Try this:

```
cell_center.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Answer (score -2):

Looks like the other answers are showing how to change the cell background color, not the label background color.

To change the **label** background color, use the following code.

```
[cell_center.textLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
```

Let me know if this doesn't work for you and we'll troubleshoot some more.

Comment: i think he uses this already which he said doesn't work.

Comment: first correct your question to wat u need?

Comment: Are you trying to set the text color? If so, try `[cell_center.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];`