# Why do we need to change the backgroundcolor of a cell in willDisplayCell?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

> Note: If you want to change the background color of a cell (by setting
>   the background color of a cell via the backgroundColor property
>   declared by UIView) you must do it in the
>   tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: method of the delegate
>   and not in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: of the data source.
>   Changes to the background colors of cells in a group-style table view
>   has an effect in iOS 3.0 that is different than previous versions of
>   the operating system. It now affects the area inside the rounded
>   rectangle instead of the area outside of it.

I noticed that changing the background color of a cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath doesn't do anything for plain style cell though it works fine on group cell.

Can anyone explain the design decision?

Also changing the background color of cell.contentView works nevertheless.

Note: I am aware of the work around of simply putting UIView and set the background on our custom TableView Cell. I am asking why and not asking how to fix it.

Comment: Look at this link maybe help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281515/how-to-customize-the-background-color-of-a-uitableviewcell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that apple override the background with the background of the table.

To really change the background, we need to do that after the overriding, and that means in:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { ... }
```

I tried and it works.