# UITableView is not using programmatic custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, customization

RESOLVED: see bottom of question.

I am using a custom UITableViewCell for my programmatically defined UITableView. The custom UITableViewCell currently has a red background and nothing else.  Here is the snippet from the UIViewController’s cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CCTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CELL_ID];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
       cell = [self getNewCell];
    }
    …
    return cell;
}

- (CCTableViewCell *) getNewCell
{
    return [CCTableViewCell newCell];
}
```

Related code in CCTableViewCell:

in the .h:

```
#define CELL_ID @"CCTVCell"
```

in the .m:

```
+ (CCTableViewCell *) newCell
{
    CCTableViewCell * cell = [[CCTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CELL_ID];
    return cell;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        [self initCell];
    }
    return self;
}

- (CCTableViewCell *) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self initCell];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) initCell
{
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```

The issue is that the custom UITableViewCell is not being used (either not displaying or not being created) in the table. Instead, a standard cell is being used.

I looked at a lot of other questions and all are solved by steps I've already implemented.

Note: The separation of parts in this is since this will be a parent class to specific UITableViewControllers with their own implementations of CCTableViewCell. This part has the common code for inheritance.

EDIT: CCTableViewCell code added

EDIT++:

This is in my UIViewController's viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 220, 300)];

    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;
    [tableView registerClass:[CCTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CELL_ID];
    [tableView reloadData];

    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
}
```

EDIT++: The TableViewController is really UIViewController with the delegate and datasource set up

EDIT: RESOLVED:
So it turns out that overwriting the willDisplayCell delegate works. See the link below for information.

[How to customize the background color of a UITableViewCell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281515/how-to-customize-the-background-color-of-a-uitableviewcell)

Essentially, cellForRowAtIndexPath seems to only do things post-creation of the table. The willDisplayCell works whenever the cell is displayed. My guess is that the project created blank cells when creating the table in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Add the code for `CCTableViewCell`

Comment: try replacing this line:
CCTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CELL_ID];

by:

CCTableViewCell *cell = (CCTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CELL_ID];

I am not sure if thats the reason... wont lose anything if you try.. good luck

Comment: One more thing, where do you load your custom cell NIB ?

Comment: I would do it this way ::  

if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CELL_ID owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

Comment: I do not have a pre-existing nib. This is why I put the title as "programmatic UITableViewCell"
@DrDev thanks for the attempt. It didn't do anything new.

Comment: Yeah I just realized... Will let you know if i have any other ideas..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that overwriting the willDisplayCell delegate works. See the link below for information.

[How to customize the background color of a UITableViewCell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281515/how-to-customize-the-background-color-of-a-uitableviewcell)

Essentially, cellForRowAtIndexPath seems to only do things post-creation of the table. The willDisplayCell works whenever the cell is displayed. My guess is that the project created blank cells when creating the table in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` or `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` after your tableView has been created? This is what tells your table view to use your custom class/nib when creating a cell. You would likely do this in the `viewDidLoad` method of your view controller.

As of iOS 6 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: always returns a cell if you have registered a class using one of the `register???:forCellReuseIdentifier:` methods. Previously it would return nil if a free cell was not available. You don't need to test `cell == nil` if you are building for iOS 6.

EDIT:
You mention this is a TableViewController. I assume this means your view controller is a subclass of UITableViewController. If this is the case there is already an instance if UITableView available via the `tableView` property and no need to create one in your viewDidLoad method. Instead I would change your code to look like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;
    [[self tableView] registerClass:[CCTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CELL_ID];
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
}
```

In fact, you might not have to set the delegate and dataSource properties if you are using a UITableViewController (I'm not sure if this is already done for you). Have you tried adding an NSLog in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to be sure it's being called?

Comment: @Alex Your first paragraph isn't true if you don't use one of the "registerXXX:forCellReuseIdentifier:" methods.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for the note. I'll edit my comment to reflect this information.

Comment: The TableViewController is actually a TableView with the delegate and datasource set up. Sorry for the confusion. I will update my post.

Comment: Thank you for the attempts. It turned out it was a different path. I'd give you vote-up for answering, but I just joined and don't have enough rep yet.