# How do I change colour of tableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I need to change the white colour of  cells to my custom color
[Here is the supported image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vUB1.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize the background color of a UITableViewCell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281515/how-to-customize-the-background-color-of-a-uitableviewcell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor() // Your Color
```

Comment: add it to my ViewDidLoad() ?

Comment: Nope in this method : func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { }

Comment: Did you implemented tableview delegate and datasource methods ?

Comment: is there a way to change the font family and font colour ?

Comment: Yup,Like this : cell.textLabel.font = UIFont(name:"Avenir", size:22)