# How to change the backgroud view at uitablviewcell when it turns to editing mode

Tags: ios, objective-c

[here's my tableview cell editing mode image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLPsp.png)

I want to change the check image background view turn to clear color, but I don't know how to do, could anyone help me solve this problem?

here's my code

```
for (UIControl *control in self.subviews){

    if ([control isMemberOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UITableViewCellEditControl")]){

        for (UIView *v in control.subviews) {

            if ([v isKindOfClass: [UIImageView class]]) {
            UIImageView *img=(UIImageView *)v;
                if (self.selected) {
                    img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"check"];
                }else{
                    img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck"];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281515/how-to-customize-the-background-color-of-a-uitableviewcell)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customize the background color of a UITableViewCell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281515/how-to-customize-the-background-color-of-a-uitableviewcell)

Answer (score 0):

You would normally do that kind of thing on the cell level rather. You can test for editing mode by making a function like `configureCell` and update the image accordingly. Something like this...

```
if (editing){
    [self.checkImage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    }
else {
    [self.checkImage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:.8 green:.8 blue:1 alpha:1]];
    }
```

then call that function from your `cellForRowAt indexPath` or from `willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath` or one of the many others available for UITableViews.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: I tried this method, but it only change the image background color, but what I want to change is the color of the imageview's Superview , but I don't know how to get the superview and change the superview's frame.

Comment: Have you tried [self.superview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];